# Open Android library located in subfolder in Eclipse

Tags: android

Many Android libraries are distributed using a similar structure as follows:

```
mycustomlib/
-->lib/ (where the "real" code lives)
---->src/
-->samples/
-->tests/
```

I want to import the library to Eclipse, but I cant import the whole `mycustomlib` folder because it has no `AndroidManifest.xml` file (I suppose this is the reason). I only can import the `lib` folder. Apparently works, but the project name in Eclipse becomes `lib`.

Is there any way to put `mycustomlib` in the project name without messing the tree structure so I can pull git changes normally?

My reason to want to do this:
If I keep a generic name as `lib` as the project name, this would confuse the management of multiple projects in the same workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rename the project inside Eclipse (by clicking on the project and pressing F2).

It will change a Eclipse-specific file called `.project` (it will not rename the folder). Since many projects don't have this file or not modify it, there is no problem in changing it. At worst, just do the merge manually to any changes in the file.

Answer (score 0):

why you must import all `mycustomlib` , just import `lib`, `sample` , modify and pull to original git

Comment: In that case I'll have a generic name as project name, which would confuse the management of multiple projects in the same workspace.

Comment: oh, i see, just rename it. i think eclipse will don't change your folder name